# Is Tafseer Ibn Katheer at archives.org Authentic?

Tags: tafseer, authenticity, books

I found Tafseer Ibn Katheer at [archive.org](https://archive.org/details/TafseerIbnKathirenglish114SurahsComplete). There are no reviews on the page. I want to confirm if it is authentic.

Comment: This needs details: authentic in what context? Also note that these kinds of request hardly go ahead with our site policies as there seems no general profit from answering this inquiry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a digitized version of the [translation published by Dar us Salam](https://dar-us-salam.com/quran/tafseer/q09-tafsir-ibn-kathir.html), a scanned copy of which is present at archive.org [here](https://archive.org/details/TafsirIbnKathirVolume0110English) and [here](https://archive.org/details/tafsir_ibn_kathir).

This translation is *abridged*, the translators fully translated some parts and they have summarized some things and omitted others.

Comment: Is there any explanation for what was the basis for the translators ro abridge... unfortunately there are soo many abridged versions of tafsir ibn Kathir so it seems hard to find an exact source even for pages such as qtafsir.

Comment: @Medi1Saif — It is in the introduction of the book (English translation). They followed the same methodology of As-Sābūni, which removed the discussions of the multiple chains of narrations of hadiths (long as there is an authentic chain), the discussions about jurisprudence rulings, and the discussions about the origin of Arabic words. The original tafsīr was not translated to the best of my knowledge.